# AttributeError: module 'app.management.commands.api' has no attribute 'Command'

Tags: python, django, api

I have a file to fetch info from a API (UK Company House).  To test I have

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://api.companieshouse.gov.uk/company/00002065', auth=('xxxxx', ''))
print(r.text)
```

It works and produces the data, but then after the data I get the following error message

> AttributeError: module 'app.management.commands.api' has no attribute
>   'Command'

Why is this and how do I resolve?

Edit - Additionally, if I run "py ch_api.py" in the same folder the file is located it works with no error; only when I run "py manage.py ch_scrape" I get the error (I need to run it through the second method)

Edit 2 - Some further info

Files

```
 project
 ├── __init__.py
 ├── manage.py
 ├── fetches
     ├── management
         ├── __init__.py
         ├── commands
             ├── ch_api.py
             ├── __init__.py
 └── project
     ├── __init__.py
     ├── asgi.py
     ├── settings.py
     ├── urls.py
     ├── views.py
     ├── wsgi.py
```

My manage.py file

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Django's command-line utility for administrative tasks."""
import os
import sys

def main():
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'project.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

My settings.py file

```
"""
Django settings for project project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.0.2.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '*******'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'project.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'project.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'assets'),
)
```

Comment: There's not enough information here to help you fix this - please post code that would allow someone to reproduce the problem. The error message suggests that your management command file is missing a `Command` class, which is what Django looks for when running a management command.

Comment: That is the entire code in the file - I have added my folders & files should it help and the "manage.py" and "settings.py" files, however, this is just a new Django Project with a "fetches" app the addition of the API file in management > commands.  If anyone requires any further info, just let me know.  Again, the actual function works fine but ends with that error which I need to fix - Additionally - if I run py ch_api.py it works with no error; only when I run py manage.py ch_scrape I get the error (I need to run it through the second method)

Comment: Suggest you read the documentation on how to write a management command: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-management-commands/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - got it.  Coming from Rails, I'm not sure what or why Command(BaseCommand) is required, but learning as I go.  If anyone wants to pop a small nudge to what this is all about, it would be appreciated.

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
import requests

class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):

        r = requests.get('https://api.companieshouse.gov.uk/company/00002065', auth=('DKvKM78qjU0Er_PGYnAdfSpgNquuz9LA_GYp1KNY', ''))
        print(r.text)
```